# Are there any satellite email reflectors?

Tags: vhf, satellites

I'm just getting started using amateur satellites and would like to subscribe to an email reflector, but I can't find one. Is there anything out there?

Comment: Hello Rick, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are.

https://www.amsat.org/mailman/listinfo/amsat-bb

[There are others](https://www.google.com/search?q=amateur+satellite+email+reflector).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Mike!

Comment: Glad to help. If the answer has solved your problem, please upvote it and [click the checkmark icon](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) on the left to mark it accepted. [This helps keep track of which problems are still unsolved and gives you a little bonus](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).